# How does `also` in Kotlin returns the old value?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

How does `also` in Kotlin returns the old value and does the assignment as well?

Can you explain how does this Kotlin code work (preferably step by step) and it prints 1 and 2?

Also, as I know, in Kotlin, functions can not reassign the values and why it does not throw an error?

```
fun <T> T.myAlso(block: (T) -> Unit): T {
    block(this)
    return this
}

fun main() {
    var a = 1
    println(a.myAlso { a = 2 })
    println(a)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: All variables are just references (except unboxed primitives but it's not relevant here). What you're missing is that you're not invoking `myAlso` for `a`, you're invoking it for **current value** of `a` which is `1`. Whatever happens inside `block` is irrelevant for value returned by `myAlso`.

Comment: But it actually changes `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myAlso()` function is a [function with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types).  So it effectively has two parameters: the receiver (a `T` value), and a block of code.  Within the body of the function, the receiver is called `this`.

Your function calls the block of code, passing the receiver value; then it returns that same receiver value.

Also note that `a` is `var`, so it can be reassigned.  (It would be read-only if it were a `val`.  This basic syntax is described in [the language docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#variables).)

So, let's try to explain what happens, step by step…

Within `main()`, `a` is initially set to 1.

The tricky bit is the `a.myAlso { a = 2 }` expression.  That calls `myAlso()`, passing the value of `a` as the receiver (i.e. 1), and the block of code.  It calls the block of code, passing the receiver value of 1; the block ignores that, but instead assigns `a` the value 2.  However, that doesn't change the function's receiver, which is still 1; that's what it returns, and hence what the first
`println()` prints.

Of course, now `a` is 2, so that's what the second `println()` prints.

Comment: To be exact, is not `this` and `a` the reference to the same object?

Comment: I want to know exactly that, why it does not change receiver if it changes `a`

Comment: Think of `this` as another function parameter.  In Kotlin, parameters are passed by value.  When calling your function, the compiler reads the current value of `a` (1), and gives that value to `this`.  Within the function, `this` can't be changed — but it has no further connection to `a`.  And because `a` is `var`, there's nothing stopping _that_ from being a different value.

Comment: So basically `this` reference will get deleted?

Comment: because I checked `this` is same as `a` before calling `block` and different after it.

Comment: Ah, Actually no. They are different initially. This is because `a` is 1. Integer pool stuff.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  `this` only exists during the execution of `myAlso()`, just as `block` does.  — And StackOverflow isn't suited to question-and-answer sessions.

Comment: So `this` and `a` are different objects, finally?

Comment: `this` and `a` are variables. When `a` is created, it holds a reference to an `Int` object representing 1.  When the function is executed, its `this` parameter holds the same reference.  During its execution, `a` gets reassigned a reference to a different `Int` object representing 2; `this` still has the reference to 1.  After the function exits, the `this` parameter no longer exists.  (If that was the last reference to 1, that object would then be eligible for garbage collection; but in this case it won't be, due to constant pooling.)

Comment: Okay, I understand everything but only one thing though. How can `myAlso` see variable `a`, it is defined in main function scope. Like when we pass this function body.

Comment: Because the lambda expression `{ a = 2 }` is a [closure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#closures), which can capture variables in an outer scope.  (It's all there in the language docs.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into those carefully